# How to check whether data is modified?

Tags: algorithm

I have a web app, which allows users to edit several configurations. I want to make the users aware that they have made changed locally but not committed since their last load. When users change the configuration back, the "modified flag" should disappear.

What's a good approach to achieve it? Currently, I am thinking about keeping an original copy of the configurations, and compare current configuration with the original one each time the user made some changes, but I am worried about the performance since the configuration data is fairly large. (The app client runs in browsers.)

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think performance will be an issue but if it were, I'd also create a "dirty field" map based on associative array or a hashmap/object with field names as keys. Of course all field names must be unique. This map will be initially empty.

When you edit any field, catch the onChange or onBlur event and compare just this field with the saved one. If they differ, put it to the dirty map like `field_map['field1'] = true;`. If they are equal, remove this key from the dirty map.

So, if your dirty map is not empty, you will know changes were made, and you will also know exactly what fields have changed.